# How to parse a JSON file in Python

Tags: python

I am still new to python in general. I'm currently trying to read in this JSON file I extracted from this site:

https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-115th-congress-members/table/?rows=100&lang=EN&refine.rep_sen=Senator&exclude.rep_sen=Representative

However, when I read it in using:

```
senators_json = pd.read_json('us-115th-congress-members.json', orient = 'columns')
senators_json
```

I can't seem to access the fields I am really looking for (in the fields column). Am I completely off base in how to read in json files?

[Current Code Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wbHJ.png)

Comment: I think your issue is the json is nested. So when you read it in with read_json, the fields column is still in json format. What would you ultimately like to get? Do you only need the data from the fields column or do you want data from all columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape the data a bit first. This seems to be what you want:

```
j = json.load(open('/tmp/us-115th-congress-members.json', 'r'))
df = pd.DataFrame(v['fields'] for v in j) 
df.columns
```

Gives:

```
Index(['district', 'geo_point_2d', 'geo_shape', 'geoid', 'image', 'name', 'party', 'rep_sen', 'state_code', 'state_label', 'url'], dtype='object')
```

The `v['fields'] for v in j` in the second line is a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to map each item in original list to the "fields" key of each item.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are looking for lies in the "fields" column, which holds dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("us-115th-congress-members.json")

df.shape
# (544, 5)

df.columns
Index(['datasetid', 'fields', 'geometry', 'record_timestamp', 'recordid'], dtype='object')

df["fields"][0].keys()
# dict_keys(['rep_sen', 'name', 'district', 'state_label', 'url', 'image', 'geo_point_2d', 'geo_shape', 'party', 'state_code', 'geoid'])

df["fields"][0]["name"]
# 'Palmer, Gary J.'
```

You may use directly the json module, as it would as easy to deal with the data in this case:

```
import json
with open("us-115th-congress-members.json", "rt") as f:
    df = json.load(f)

df[0].keys()
# dict_keys(['datasetid', 'recordid', 'fields', 'geometry', 'record_timestamp'])
```